# Using free-form linguistic input in a dynamic input field

Tags: dynamic, free-form-input

I've been playing around with dynamic input fields; here's a basic example, which just consists of an input field where the user can enter a function and then a button that can be clicked to graph the function.  What I'm wondering is: is there a way to allow free-form linguistic input to be entered in the input field?  Right now, I must enter regular Mathematica syntax like Cos[x] to get a graph, but I'd really like to be able to enter something like "cos x".  (Ultimately, I'd like my dynamic module to do more than just graph the function, which is why I don't want to just use Wolfram Alpha directly.)

```
DynamicModule[{graph, f, button},
 graph = Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 480, Background -> White];
 f = Cos[x];

 button = Button["Graph!",
   graph = Plot[f, {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 480, Background -> White];
   ];

 Panel[
  Grid[{
    {InputField[Dynamic[f]], button},
    {Dynamic[graph], SpanFromLeft}},
   Spacings -> {2, 1}, Alignment -> {Left, Baseline}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that *Mathematica* feeds the input string in free-form linguistic input to the function `WolframAlpha`.  Try something like

```
Manipulate[
 If[in =!= "", WolframAlpha[in], "Enter input"],
 {{in, ""}, InputField[Dynamic[in], String] &}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate output]

---

**Response to comment**

I can't find a definitive statement in the documentation that an internet connection is required for all free-form linguistic input, but the following suggests that it is (just as I thought, too).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  I really just want the input form of the function, and it looks like I can get it by doing something like `WolframAlpha[f, {{"Input", 1}, "Input"}]`

This is a separate question, but does all of the free-form linguistic input require an internet connection?  I see that the WolframAlpha command certainly does, and ideally I'd use something that worked offline as well.

Comment: @Janet I believe an internet connection is required.  See update.

Comment: Thanks!  The same thing happens when I try it offline, so that must just be how it is.